# Removing whitespace and then empty lines from an array of strings

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, filter, whitespace

I've read a text file into a big string:

```
fileText = try NSString(contentsOfFile: pathToFile, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as String
```

(I omitted the do/catch part and fileText was declared as an optional string constant before the assignment).

Now I split the lines out into an array of strings, trim the whitespace from each, and then remove any empty strings:

```
let lines = (fileText!.components(separatedBy: "\n")).map { $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)}.filter {$0.count > 0}
```

And it works fine, but I'm learning Swift 4 and I suspect there's a cleaner way to accomplish my task, right? I would appreciate any examples that put my code to shame. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem of your code, is that you iterate through all String charecters for four times. But task can be complete only iterating once. Something like this:

```
let myString = String() // String received from any source
var lines = [String]()
var line = ""

myString!.forEach {
   switch $0 {
   case " ":
      break
   case "\n":
      if line.count > 0 {
         lines.append(line)
         line = ""
      }
   default:
      line += String($0)
   }
}

print(lines)
```

For test file:

```
$ cat test.txt 
123123123 12312312
123 12312312 12312312
sfsdfsdfsfsdf
sdfsdf 23234 sdfsdfs 23234
sdfsdf 

sdfsdfsdf
```

Result will be:

```
$ swift main.swift 
["12312312312312312", "1231231231212312312", "sfsdfsdfsfsdf", "sdfsdf23234sdfsdfs23234", "sdfsdf", "sdfsdfsdf"]
```